# Compare two elements using Xpath in Web table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, html-table

I am using Selenium + Python, don't forget about it when you will write an answer, please.

So the case is - I need to check that "green arrow" number same with the "red arrow" number.

This numbers always generate with different numbers. So I make a variable "first_value" for the "red arrow" and "second_value" for the "green arrow". And everything is working fine, but I use ugly Xpath, so I want to make my Xpath's a little bit more beautiful, but no idea how can I do in this case.

Here is my code:

```
<tr class="GridPager_Default">
<td align="left" valign="top" colspan="27"><span id="Rad305104_ctl01_ctl03_ctl02_StatusLabel" style="float:left;">Ready</span></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr class="GridAltRow_Default">
<td>77915481</td>
<td style="display:none;">False</td>
<td style="display:none;">False</td>
<td>77915315</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>2020-05-27 07:59:47</td>
<td>77915413</td>
...
</tr>
```

and also before there is a very big part of the code, so i cant paste it here, so i make a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcYWQ.png). [The arrows to compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuh88.png).

I try these examples, but all of them gives me a message:

> Exception has occurred: TimeoutException

P.S. For the second one I use ugly Xpath for this moment.

```
first_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class=GridAltRow_Default'][2]/td[7]"))).text

second_value = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]"), (first_value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my mind :

With the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And using XPath :

```
value1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='GridAltRow_Default'][1]/td[1]"))).getText()
value2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='GridAltRow_Default'][2]/td[7]"))).getText()
print(value1 == value2)
```

This should output `TRUE`.

EDIT : I'm not sure you're passing the variable correctly in your second XPath expression. What I would try :

```
value1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='GridAltRow_Default'][2]/td[7]"))).getText()

value2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/table//tr[4]/td/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table//tr[5]/td/table//tr[2]/td/div/div/table//tr[1]/td[1]"), "%s" % value1))
```

Comment: I cant use in your way, but when I do like that then I still getting at "Time Exception" error:

first_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='GridAltRow_Default'][2]/td[7]"))).text

second_value = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='GridAltRow_Default'][1]/td[1]"), (first_value)))


When I use my ugly Xpath for first_value then above second_value getting exception, and if I use above first_value then it getting me exception warning

I cant use "visibility_of_element_located" for second_value as an "argument" error

Comment: Still "Exception has occurred: TimeoutException" for the value1=(

Comment: OK. I've edited my answer. There was a missing `'` and a useless `until` in the first expression.